# How to show empty field when date is undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I have datepicker:

```
  <md-datepicker class="dateContainer" ng-model="startDate">
        </md-datepicker>
```

Start date get from service:

```
scope.startDate = getMinStartDateMetadata(item)

 function getMinStartDateMetadata (item) {
        var minDate;
        if((item.start_date == null)|| (item.start_date == "")) {
            minDate = null;
            return minDate;
        }
        var startDate = new Date(item.start_date);
        return startDate;
    }
```

the issue is  - when there is no item.start_date it returns undefined, and shows 'undefined' in datepicker filed. I want to show NOTHING in datepicker field when date is undefined.

How to do it?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use below ternary operator to return:

```
return startDate===undefined?"":startDate;
```

Here is plukner code for verification https://plnkr.co/edit/J89A2FZM0HUfWrazFDz5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can simply replace your if clause with:

```
if (!item.start_date) { //YOUR CODE }
```

it will include undefined and null values

Comment: when date is undefined, I just don't want to show 'undefined' in datepisker, just want to show empty ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMinStartDateMetadata (item) {
return item.start_date?new Date(item.start_date):'';
}
```

---

```
<md-datepicker class="dateContainer" value="No Date Defined" ng-model="startDate">
        </md-datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

That is required. [See API](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) So, it should be **always a valid Javascript Date object**. You cannot assign it to something else.

Instead, i recomment you to use another flag to hide datepicker (for example using ng-if (not ng-show) `like ng-if="showDatePicker"`) and assign that to a specific date object.

Comment: can I create Date object with no date?

Comment: No, it is not possible too. the object you give `startDate` should always be a Date object. Just use a flag to hide it. This would be even better way to assign a value to undefined in some state of an app.

Comment: I will try to use pcaleholder in datepicker: so at the begining it should show some date or empty